# Manifest.mf file viewer?

Tags: java, jar, osgi, manifest

Are there any tools available which will take a manifest.mf file from a jar and display the contents nicely?

In particular when working with OSGi bundles the Export-Package and Import-Package entries can get quite large and difficult to quite work out what is going on. Added to this simple keyword text searching is not 100% reliable because of line breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the eclipse plugin for [BND tools](http://bndtools.org/) does it fairly nicely.  It has an editor for viewing a jar file.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was after - the JAR editor only shows the manifest file as plain text but the BND Bundle Editor seems able to open a jar file and parse and display the import pkgs nicely (+1) but not the export or private pkgs (-1).

Comment: Actually that is not correct. If you have added your Jar file to your cnf Repository, you only have to click on the bundle in the Repository view and then have a look to the "Imports/Exports" view. There you will see what kind of packages will be imported and what kind of packages are exported. but of course not the private ones, bc they are still private ;)

Comment: Note that in recent version of Bndtools you can install the JAR editor as a standalone component, i.e. you don't have to install the whole of Bndtools if you don't want to.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the bnd.jar from Maven Central.
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/biz/aQute/bnd/bnd/2.2.0/bnd-2.2.0.jar

And yes, I can run it and it pretty-prints the manifest:

```
java -jar bnd-2.2.0.jar example.jar
```

The print command shows Import-Package and Export-Package even nicer:

```
java -jar bnd-2.2.0.jar print example.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an online pretty-printer for manifest files, with optional sorting:

https://robinst.github.io/jar-manifest-formatter/

Answer (score 3):

Here is an online pretty printer of manifests;
https://apinx.dk/javamanifest/

You can drag'n'drop the .jar file or copy-paste the manifest.mf itself.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I tried to drag the manifest into the box like they said, but nothing happened.

Comment: @Azurespot; I'm the author of this site and you are right. Non-zip file manifests were not handled correctly - they are now. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

bnd itself can be run from the command line and will print all details:

```
 java -jar biz.aQute.bnd.run.jar xx.jar
```

You can also click on a jar in bndtools and select the print tab, this gives you more details than you probably need.

bnd can be download from https://bndtools.ci.cloudbees.com/job/bnd.master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/bundles/biz.aQute.bnd/biz.aQute.bnd-latest.jar

Type bnd help for information about the commands.

Comment: The cloudbees link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Parse it in javascript ;) Here's a **JSFiddle** to pretty-print an OSGi MANIFEST.MF file:

http://jsfiddle.net/scotch/5WJwd/embedded/result/

```
var sectionsText = text.split(/\n\n\n/),
    sections = {},
    sectionText,
    name,
    body,
    packagesText,
    packages,
    packageName,
    packageBody;

for (var i in sectionsText) {
    sectionText = sectionsText[i];
    name = sectionText.substr(0, sectionText.indexOf(": "));
    body = sectionText.substr(sectionText.indexOf(": ") + 2);
    sections[name] = body;

    if (name.indexOf("Package") != -1) {
        body = body.replace(/[\n\r] /g, '');
        body = body.replace(/(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/g, "$1\n");
        packagesText = body.split(/\n/);
        packages = {};
        for (var i in packagesText) {
            packageBody = packagesText[i];
            packageName = packageBody.substr(0, packageBody.indexOf(";"));
            packageBody = packageBody.substr(packageBody.indexOf(";")+1);

            if (collapse) {
                packageBody = packageBody.replace(/uses:="[^"]*"/g, 'uses:="..."');
            }

            packages[packageName] = packageBody;//.replace(/;/g, ';\n');
        }
        sections[name] = packages;
    }
}
```

It sorts entries by alphabetical order too, so you can compare them. Hope it will be useful for someone (especially people developing outside of Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse you can use the Plugin Manifest Editor configured by

[image]

Comment: Eclipse won't open the jar file itself, you would have to create a project from it first before using the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I opened my jar in [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) (any unzipper/unarchiver will do), then you have the option to copy the MANIFEST.MF file elsewhere in your computer. I copied it to my desktop, then opened with Visual Studio Code. Any text editor would have worked.

Alternatively, I opened the jar with [Atom](https://atom.io/). It showed the entire tree structure of my jar. I double-clicked the MANIFEST.MF file and it opened right up in Atom.